# Progress SQL error in ssis package: buffer too small for generated record

Tags: ssis, etl, openedge, progress-db

I have an `ssis` package which uses `SQL command` to get data from Progress database. Every time I execute the query, it throws this specific error:

> ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Internal error -1 (buffer too small for generated record) in SQL from subsystem RECORD SERVICES function recPutLONG called from sts_srtt_t:::add_row on (ttbl# 4, len/maxlen/reqlen = 33/32/33) for . Save log for Progress technical support.

I am running the following query:

```
Select max(ROWID) as maxRowID from TableA
GROUP BY ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC,ColumnD
```

Comment: Do u have `linked server` configured correctly

Comment: Hi, yes, all the other queries are working fine except for this one. So linked server is configured correctly.

Comment: It looks like similar to memory exception, try adding column names on query as you are using `group by`

Comment: There would be maximum length of column in progress will be less than 32k, your query might be returning `int` value more than that

Comment: Hi, I have asked the person who has access to the database to run the query. And it runs fine in the database. Not sure why it is not running in ssis? Any ideas?

Comment: Did u ask him what is the max value from query ?

Comment: Hm... as the message states: your query returns one value with a length of 33 where only 32 is allowed... and do you have the specification of the function recPutLONG?

Comment: Hi I have asked the person who has the access to the database and the max value is '0000000000041211541'

Comment: this could be a type mismatch issue - try converting the rowid to bigint or decimal

Comment: Hi, i have tried to convert to decimal and also, to bigint. Nothing seems to work. In the group by, if I remove column4, it works fine. Column4 only has one distinct value. So not sure why its not working with it in the group by.

Comment: So, what is Column4  and what is the distincat value it contains?

Comment: Quite aside from the error why do you want to know the MAX ROWID?

Comment: Hi, column4 only has two letters called 'EM'. Tom Bascom. I have not written this query, it was done by another developer who join tables using max IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error.
After change startup-parameter `-SQLTempStorePageSize` and `-SQLTempStoreBuff` to `24` and `3000` respectively the problem was solved.
I think, for you the values must be changed to `40` and `20000`.

You can find more information [here](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P158011). The name of the parameter in that article was a bit different than in my Database, it depends on the Progress-version witch is used.